# vim match a mark in regexp

Tags: regex, vim, selection

In gvim (v8) regexp we can specify a point in the selected region with `\%V, e.g. s/\%Vabc/xyz/`. However, `\%V` matches anywhere in the selection, I want something to match only at the beginning or end of the visual-selection (marks `<,`>).

Moreover this regexp `/\%V\_.*\%V/` doesn't select the final character of the region. `\%V` is supposed to be zero-width?

So how can I specify the position of a mark, as in:

`:s/\mark(`<).*\zs(abc)\ze\mark.*(>)/xyz/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `\%V` is zero-width; to include the last selected character, you need to append a `.` to include the last character: `/\%V\_.*\%V./`

There are special atoms for mark positions; you can use them with the `'<,'>` marks, too: `/\%'<.*\%'>./`. As they are zero-width, too, the above applies here, too, so it's not a better alternative.